# how to use Custom Progress bar in Asynk task in android

Tags: android

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int DIALOG_LOADING = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, doSomeTask);
        thread.start();

    }


    private Runnable doSomeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Code of your task
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            //Done! now continue on the UI thread
            runOnUiThread(taskDone);
        }
    };

    //Since we can't update our UI from a thread this Runnable takes care of that!
    private Runnable taskDone = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
        }
    };



@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_LOADING:
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                //here we set layout of progress dialog
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                return dialog;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    };
```

Using Upper code i am able to show Custom Progress bar but it set on thread with Specified time but i have asynk task below .

```
   class download extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

i want to set Here Progress bar  once do in background finish then progress bar should disappear.please suggest me

Comment: Start progress bar inside `onPreExecute()` and stop it inside `onPostExecute`.

Comment: use progress dialog in onPreExecute and in onPostExecute

Comment: when i try to call         showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
 in on Preexcute it Error COming

Comment: Is your Async Task outside the LoginActivity?

Comment: NO same class i have use  that Asynk taske

Comment: used progress=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Downloading Music");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setProgress(0);
        progress.show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AsyncTask, you can show your dialog in onPreExecute() and after downloaded your data in onPostExecute() you can dismiss it. Start your download task into doInBackground().

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    private Activity activity;
    private static final int DIALOG_LOADING = 1;
    public Download(Activity activity){
         this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // before start download task
        activity.showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
         // start dowanload task here
         return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // after downloaded data
        activity.dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(TabsActivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dialog.dismiss();              
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run()
{
    // your code here
}
};

 Thread t = new Thread(r);
 t.start();
```

AsyncTask task

```
class download extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING); //custom alert start when AsyncTask start

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
  dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);  //custom dialog  Dissmiss when AsyncTask completed

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i just modify

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int DIALOG_LOADING = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        new download().execute();

    }


   class download extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //do your stuff here 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
    }
}


@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_LOADING:
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                //here we set layout of progress dialog
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                return dialog;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);  , dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);  this line coming Error can not ressolve

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public SavePatientData(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = null;
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
    pDialog.setMax(100);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMessage("Saving\n .....");
    pDialog.setContentView(// your coustom layout);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // do someting
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if ((pDialog != null) && (pDialog.isShowing())) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}